# Post fields in this format with Retrofit

Tags: android, json, api, retrofit, androidhttpclient

So I need to send an API request in this format

> {
>       "access_key": "6477848488cchfc47488",
>       "person": {
>           "first_name": "John",
>           "last_name": "Henry",
>           "email": "john@henry.com"
>       }
>   }

I have created an object

```
public class Person {
    public String first_name = "";
    public String last_name = "";
    public String email = "";
}
```

In my interface I have

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/send_details")
void sendDetails(@Field("person") Person person, @Field("access_key") String accessKey, Callback<User> cb);
```

Finally in my Activity I have the code below to call the  send details method

```
Person person = new Person("John", ":"Henry, "john@henry.com");
  aApi.sendDetails(person, ACCESS_KEY, new Callback<User>() {
     @Override
        public void success(User user, Response response) {

        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

        }
    });
  }
```

I get a 500 Internal Server Error. I've just switched from volley to retrofit. Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `@Body` annotation instead of `@Field` and passing a single `Body` object.

```
class DetailsBody {
    @SerializedName("access_key")
    public String accessKey;
    public Person person;

    public DetailsBody(String accessKey, Person person) {
        this.accessKey = accessKey;
        this.person = person;
    }
}
```

and then:

```
@POST("/send_details")
void sendDetails(@Body DetailsBody body, Callback<User> cb);
```

(without `@FormUrlEncoded`)